# Unable to insert strings into MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, string

To add new records to the MySQL DB, I have used PHP to insert the data. So far however, I have been unable to pass strings into their fields. I have been able to pass integers into my field "ID" though.

I have been trying URL's such as www.example.com/newArticle?Headline="testString", the response is "Records added to the database" but when i look on the console, no new records have been added.

**PHP Code:**

```
<?PHP

$user_name = "createyo_james";
$password = "password";
$database = "createyo_TestDatabase";
$server = "localhost";

$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

if ($db_found) {

$Headline = $_GET["Headline"];

$SQL = "INSERT INTO Customer (Headline) VALUES ('$Headline')";

$result = mysql_query($SQL);

mysql_close($db_handle);

print "Records added to the database";

}
else {

print "Database NOT Found ";
mysql_close($db_handle);

}

?>
```

Comment: "Records added to the database" is being returned only if the database is found not if the query was successful...

Comment: Hander errors: `$result = mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: OMG! `mysql_*` deprecated! SQL injection prone code...

Comment: Even if you should never use this in a public system (very! insecure) Please insert `echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link). "\n";` after `$result = mysql_query($SQL);` and post the output.

Comment: Output: ": Records added to the database"

Comment: @turson I added the die code which has shown me: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Headline') VALUES ('"testString"')' at line 1

Comment: Theres your answer then :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is always prefered to check if the connection to the server is successful.

Use following:

```
$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password) or die("Connection Error");
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle) or die ("DB not selected");
```

After it is successfull you may output the query to check if it is correct.

```
echo $SQL;
```

or use below:

```
$result = mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error());
```

**SQL Injection:**
You must validate your use input before using into queries

Comment: I know it is successful since i am receiving: "Records added to the database"

Comment: You will see it always because you are not using any condition on the query itself. You need to check if the query was successful using the `die()` with `mysql_query()` as above

Comment: That doesn't mean its being successful... You are returning "Records Added to the database" only if the db is found not if the query is successful. replace with if( $result = mysql_query($SQL) ) { echo "inserted correctly to database"; }

Comment: Ah i see, my response by using die() is: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Headline') VALUES ('"testString"')' at line 1

Comment: USE $Headline = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["Headline"]);

Answer (score 0):

First: Check if your MySql table has Primary Key and auto increment. 
Second: Check fields type. If is number you can't store a string.

Answer (score -2):

It looks as if your calling the query incorrectly.

Replace
      `$result=mysql_query($SQL);`

with
       `mysql_query($SQL);`